# Strongly nonlinear equation

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to find $y$ from the following nonlinear equation:
$$H=\dfrac{2}{\pi}\sin^{-1}\left(\dfrac{y}{R}\right)+2\dfrac{y}{\pi R^2}\sqrt{R^2-y^2}$$
where:
$H\in\mathbb{R},R\in\mathbb{R}$
Despite many attempts to find a closed form solution of this equation I didn't find anything. I think it's impossible to solve it analytically, so I need to find a fast numerical algorithm able to provide $y$ given $H$ and $R$. The conventional numerical approach are usually slow. Thanks.

Comment: i also think there is only a numerical way

Comment: do you have a value for $$R,H$$?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner: for example, $R=14$, $H=9$

Comment: in this case there is no solution

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner: sorry. Typo. $H=0.09$

Comment: in your case substitution $y=14sint$ reduces equation to $t+\frac{sin2t}{2}=0.09\frac{\pi}{2}$, from here $t=0.07084$, so $y=0.990428$